# Rails: backing up has many associations in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, schema

I have `User` with primary key `id` and a `Blog` model with primary key `id`.

I have a `has_many` association in `User` to the `Blog` and a `belongs_to` in `Blog`
to `User`.

From what I understand I need to manually to the modifications to the schema.

Could you provide an insight on how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :blogs
end

# app/models/blog.rb
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

# db/migrate/20131103182551_add_user_id_to_blogs.rb
class AddUserIdToBlogs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :blogs, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

Then run `rake db:migrate`. You can then call `user.blogs` or `blog.user`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do what you have already said above and then ALSO change the database schema. You change the database schema through migrations. The step that you are missing is => You need to add the foreign key of user_id to blogs (You do this through a migration) or add a belongs to relationship

You can create the migration with a 'rails generate migration' command

```
rails generate migration add_column :blogs, :user_id, :integer
```

OR

```
rails generate migration change_table :blogs, :belongs_to, :user
```

The result of the migration should add the foreign key of user_id to blogs or it should add the belongs_to association between user and blogs.

Look for the result of your migration in the db/migrate folder

Then run

```
rake db:migrate
```